# Making sure thread is in specific state

Tags: multithreading

I have two threads communicating with each other. Thread B always sends a single message to thread A and waits until thread A has processed the message, in pseudo-code:

```
// this is thread B
for(;;) {
    post_msg_to_thread_A();
    wait_for_msg_from_thread_A();
}

// this is called on thread A
void on_msg_from_thread_B() {
    // ...do something...
    post_msg_to_thread_B();
}

// this is called on thread A 
void on_button_click() {
    // is thread B waiting and will not wake up before on_button_click() exits?
}
```

**EDIT**: Now I have the following problem: In `on_button_click()` I need to tell if thread B is currently waiting on the reply message from thread A and will continue waiting on it because thread A hasn't run `on_msg_from_thread_B()` yet.

In other words, there is some code that I can only run on thread A when thread B is in waiting state and I want to know if it's safe to run that code in `on_button_click()`.

For clarification, thread A runs a main loop that will process the different messages it gets. These can be messages from thread B but it can also be UI messages like button clicks.

I think I need to set a mutex-protected flag to achieve what I want but thinking about it further really messes up my mind and I'm completely unsure if this is really the way to go because the more I think about it the more complicated this issue becomes and all my mutex ideas so far ended up in a deadlock.

So even though this is probably a rather simple multithreading problem I don't see a way to solve it so I hope somebody on here has an idea...

Comment: Since your boolean flag would be both read and written only by thread A, I don't see any reason why it needs to be mutex-protected.

Comment: But where should the flag be set to 0 then? It is set to 1 after `post_msg_to_thread_B()` but when/where should it be reset to 0 then? IMHO setting it to 0 after thread B has received the message would make sense but it contradicts your statement then...

Comment: I'd imagine you'd set it to zero inside `on_msg_from_thread_B()`, no?

Comment: Well, I guess we should say what the flag is named before talking about when to set it to what :) I was thinking of a flag named `msg_sent`. I would set this flag to 1 in `on_msg_from_thread_B()` after `post_msg_to_thread_B()`. But where to set it to 0 again?

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a mistake. My problem is not really related to telling if the reply message from thread A to thread B has been posted but I need to tell if thread B is currently waiting. Please see my edits above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words, there is some code that I can only run on thread A
>   when thread B is in waiting state and I want to know if it's safe to
>   run that code in on_button_click().

Okay, perhaps you want to do something like this, then:

```
 mutex the_shared_mutex;

 // this is thread B
 void thread_b()
 {
    lock_mutex(the_shared_mutex);

    for(;;) {
        post_msg_to_thread_A();

        unlock_mutex(the_shared_mutex);
        wait_for_msg_from_thread_A();
        lock_mutex(the_shared_mutex);
    }
 }

 // this is called on thread A
 void on_button_click() {
     lock_mutex(the_shared_mutex);
     run_the_code_that_is_only_safe_to_run_when_b_is_in_waiting_state();
     unlock_mutex(the_shared_mutex);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see where is the problem in your pseudo code. 
I can understand your question in two ways and will try to answer it in both ways.

One option is that you need to handle each button click on thread A even if response to thread B was not yet sent. If so, make a queue or counter of button clicks to thread B. 
Say you get a button click and never sent a response yet. You add the button click event to a queue or increment your button click counter, and when you send a response pop one button click event out of the queue or decrement your counter.

If you wish to not do anything with a button click if you yet didnt send a response, then all you need is a flag standing for wether you sent a response yet or not.
If you receive a button click and the flag is false, then you do nothing and keep running. If you receive a button click and the flag is true, then you handle that button click and turn the flag to false. On sending a response, you turn the flag to true.

I do not see any need for a mutex here since you do not access the same data from thread A and B. All communication between them is probably some type of IPC.

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a mistake. My problem is not really related to telling if the reply message from thread A to thread B has been posted but I need to tell if thread B is currently waiting. Please see my edits in the OP.